# How do I parse a date without zero padding, in the format (1 or 2-digit year)-(Month abbreviation)?

Tags: python

I need to parse a few dates that are roughly in the format (1 or 2-digit year)-(Month abbreviation), for example:

> 5-Jun (June 2005)
>
> 13-Jan (January 2013)

I tried using strptime with the format `%b-%y` but it did not consistently produce the desired date. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime), this is because some years in my dataset are not zero-padded.

Further, when I tested the datetime module (please see below for my code) on the string "5-Jun", I got "2019-06-05", instead of the desired result (June 2005), even if I set `yearfirst=True` when calling `parse`.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parsed = parse("5-Jun",yearfirst=True)
print(parsed)
```

Comment: you need to, at the very least, show us the definition of parse().  We can't have any idea what your code is doing if you don't show it to us.  Ideally: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - If you are trying to get someone to just give you the Python code to parse those dates, please don't do that.  Please show us your own attempt so we can help you to come to an answer on your own.

Comment: @Steve: Sorry about that - parse() is a part of the datetime module. In any case, I added the import statement to my code above.

Comment: Hi Montana.  I'm curious what you preferred about @Sandeep's answer over mine?  Mine is certainly significantly more efficient.  That answer seems like a ton of work just to conditionally put a '0' at the front of a string.  Is it because you want to allow for different formats than what you show?

Comment: @Steve: Admittedly, I saw that you had been downvoted by someone else (and Rajeesh had not). In any case, I did discover that I needed to parse formats; Rajeesh's answer was more flexible in that aspect.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier if 0 is padded to single digit years, as it can be directly converted to time using format. Regular expression is used here to replace any instance of single digit number with it's '0 padded in front' value. I've used regex from [here](https://regex101.com/r/wS6eY8/1).

**Sample code:**

```
import re
match_condn = r'\b([0-9])\b'
replace_str = r'0\1'
datetime.strptime(re.sub(match_condn, replace_str, '15-Jun'), '%y-%b').strftime("%B %Y")
```

**Output:**

```
June 2015
```

Comment: Oops! I just realized it was my fault. Please disregard the previous comment. Again, thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `str.zfill`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
d = ["5-Jun", "13-Jan"]
for date in d:
    date, month = date.split("-")
    date = date.zfill(2)
    print(datetime.datetime.strptime(date+"-"+month, "%y-%b").strftime("%B %Y"))
```

**Output:**

```
June 2005
January 2013
```

Comment: By the time you do the work to split apart the input, and since you already then know just what the two parts you have are, there's no reason to incur the cost of then putting them back together as a date string, just to turn around and parse that again.  You could be much more efficient by looking the 3-char month up in a dictionary to get 0-11 and then building a Date object using the month and year values that you then have.

Answer (score -1):

Ah. I see from @Rakesh's answer what your data is about.  I thought you needed to parse the full name of the month.  So you had your two terms %b and %y backwards, but then you had the problem with the single-digit years.  I get it now.  Here's a much simpler way to get what you want if you can assume your dates are always in one of the two formats you indicate:

```
 inp = "5-Jun"
 t = time.strptime(("0" + inp)[-6:], "%y-%b")
```

Comment: I'm really curious what someone thought was wrong with this answer.  In general, it's appreciated for both the writer and future readers if you post a comment as to why you downvoted something